# missing images in docx on inserting them with apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

I am using apache POI library to insert images into the docx. When I insert 2 to 3 images its working fine. but when I try to insert more than that, final docx document is missing some images. Please help on this and suggest a solution to resolve this issue. Image type I am using is tif. 
Code I have used to insert image is

```html
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlToken;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTNonVisualDrawingProps;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTPositiveSize2D;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.wordprocessingDrawing.CTInline;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class CustomXWPFDocument extends XWPFDocument
{
    public CustomXWPFDocument(InputStream in) throws IOException
    {
        super(in);
    }

    public void createPicture(String blipId,int id, int width, int height)
    {
        final int EMU = 9525;
        width *= EMU;
        height *= EMU;
        //String blipId = getAllPictures().get(id).getPackageRelationship().getId();


        CTInline inline = createParagraph().createRun().getCTR().addNewDrawing().addNewInline();

        String picXml = "" +
                "<a:graphic xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main\">" +
                "   <a:graphicData uri=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture\">" +
                "      <pic:pic xmlns:pic=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture\">" +
                "         <pic:nvPicPr>" +
                "            <pic:cNvPr id=\"" + id + "\" name=\"Generated\"/>" +
                "            <pic:cNvPicPr/>" +
                "         </pic:nvPicPr>" +
                "         <pic:blipFill>" +
                "            <a:blip r:embed=\"" + blipId + "\" xmlns:r=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships\"/>" +
                "            <a:stretch>" +
                "               <a:fillRect/>" +
                "            </a:stretch>" +
                "         </pic:blipFill>" +
                "         <pic:spPr>" +
                "            <a:xfrm>" +
                "               <a:off x=\"0\" y=\"0\"/>" +
                "               <a:ext cx=\"" + width + "\" cy=\"" + height + "\"/>" +
                "            </a:xfrm>" +
                "            <a:prstGeom prst=\"rect\">" +
                "               <a:avLst/>" +
                "            </a:prstGeom>" +
                "         </pic:spPr>" +
                "      </pic:pic>" +
                "   </a:graphicData>" +
                "</a:graphic>";

        //CTGraphicalObjectData graphicData = inline.addNewGraphic().addNewGraphicData();
        XmlToken xmlToken = null;
        try
        {
            xmlToken = XmlToken.Factory.parse(picXml);
        }
        catch(XmlException xe)
        {
            xe.printStackTrace();
        }
        inline.set(xmlToken);
        //graphicData.set(xmlToken);

        inline.setDistT(0);
        inline.setDistB(0);
        inline.setDistL(0);
        inline.setDistR(0);

        CTPositiveSize2D extent = inline.addNewExtent();
        extent.setCx(width);
        extent.setCy(height);

        CTNonVisualDrawingProps docPr = inline.addNewDocPr();
        docPr.setId(id);
        docPr.setName("Picture " + id);
        docPr.setDescr("Generated");
    }
}
```

Please help me on this...